# Appropriate response to HR incident

Tags: human-resources

We are interns staying at a guest house provided by the company. We had an emergency(Our hamster was shivering, and we needed a hair dryer),and to ask for help we knocked on a (female) neighbor's door(it was pretty late, a touch before midnight, but we had lost track of the time by then). She didn't answer, so we went back. A few minutes later, there's a scene at the guest house with her supervisor knocking at our doors complaining about how we have to watch our steps(in a threatening tone). What would be an appropriate response to this kind of thing?

Edit:We have apologized profusely and they seem to have let us off the hook.

Comment: Apologize and explain? As you've described it, it just sounds like a misunderstanding.

Comment: ^Apologies. Fixed the grammar.

Comment: You say it was an "emergency", which would seem to imply that asking for help by knocking on someone's door would be reasonable. You also say that you were "kinda boneheaded" for doing so. That seems inconsistent.

Comment: ^the reason I called it "boneheaded" is because we knocked on a _woman's_ door. That appears to be the entire point of the whole incident.

Comment: Your narrative in incomplete. There is stuff unsaid between "it's an emergency (involving an animal)" and "we're kinda bone headed" You're leaving me with the impression that you are asking for advice while hiding something.

Comment: ^happy now? The reason I hadn't mentioned it because it isn't relevant.

Comment: Much better. Thanks. Is the woman an employee of your company?

Comment: Yes, They're interns as well. Different departments though.

Comment: "the reason I called it "boneheaded" is because we knocked on a *woman's* door" -- How is that more "boneheaded" than knocking on a man's door?

Comment: There is a lot of company and cultural wierdness going on. Maybe you can answer a few questions: How many people are "we"? Are pets allowed on company grounds? Why don't you own a hair dryer on your own in your group? Did you quitely knock, or was it more like a group of guys talking in front of the door and knocking? Why would a hamster need a hairdryer that badly? Do women in general feel safe where you live? Is the company guesthouse private or can anyone get in?

Comment: @nvoigt okay we are 2. pets are allowed and we both are males so we don't own a hairdryer.. we knocked very softly and asked for hairdryer in a polite way. we gave a bath to our newly bought hamster, he was shivering badly because of cold that's why we needed a hairdryer to dry him. and yes our area is quite safe when it comes to women. rather we have proper guard facilities.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere had we been we wouldn't have asked the question in the first place

Comment: Is the hamster OK?

Comment: Off topic perhaps, but why the heck were you giving a hamster a bath? The only time you should ever do so is if it has something stuck on its skin/fur that is more immediately harmful (eg. poison, acid, extremely hot or cold material) than the risk of killing it with the bath itself. Suggest next time you also get a book on pet care...

Comment: I'm not convinced that a hair dryer would be the best way to warm up a cold wet hamster, unless you're *very* careful. Having a blast of hot air applied to your head is one thing; having it applied to your entire body could be something else entirely. BTW, you never answered my previous question. (There's no indication in your story that alcohol was involved, but if it was that might explain a few things.)

Answer (score 4):

Apologize. And *mean it*. Make sure this never happens again.

From what I can make of your story, you need to behave more professional in the future. It's a company's guest house, not a frat party room. You don't go out in groups knocking on people's doors after hours. If you want to have fun, go out.

Comment: Might that be a little harsh? We don't know the details of what happens, but if there were a genuine emergency, knocking on a neighbor's door might be appropriate. Or maybe it was a "boneheaded" thing to do; we don't have enough information.

Comment: @KeithThompson In a genuine emergency situation, you don't go back to your room if the person does not open the door. If just doing nothing is an option, it's not an emergency.

Comment: After failing to get help, going back to your room to deal with the emergency  yourself might have still be the best option. Again, we just don't have enough information. I'll post a comment on the question asking for clarification.

Comment: Just to respond: we _did_ go back to our own room after knocking.

Comment: Hello, this is after a long time and i would be frank if i said i forgot about this, the truth is it was a misunderstanding, the girl on whose door we knocked on, was made uncomfortable by someone who was residing in our room before us. she thought we are the same and hence complained. when we talked to our HR about this, she set up an inquiry and we were not guilty, the girl later apologized to us. I am really sorry as i never looked at this thread after the girl apologized.

Answer (score 0):

You apologized profusely. That's good enough.

Having said that, you could have phoned her first. Alternatively, you could have reached out to her supervisor and have the supervisor contact her since it was way late in the evening.

Comment: If waking another colleague is inappropriate, instead waking said colleagues *boss* seems to be a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: @nvoigt I'd rather wake up her boss than wake her. I don't care to run  around scared about what my bosses or in this case, what someone else's boss might do to me. The worst that happens is that he screams because I woke him up from his beauty sleep, and I can take that.